# connect to mainWidget

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I have tree widgets structure, main widget has pointers to children widgets and chilrdren widget has pointers to their chirldrens and so on... How leaves (chirldrens) can get data from mainWidget and connect all widgets(for examples, mainWidget has changed input file). I used signal to connect them,but it looks like spaghetti code.Is there a better way? Maybee mediator pattern? Thanks.

```
 //MainWidget 
 class mainWidget: public QMainWindow {
      .......
      private:
        Level1AWidget *l1aw;
        Level1BWidget *l1bw;
      .......
 }
```

mainWidget creates l1aw and l1bw objects in constructor

```
  mainWidget::mainWidget(parent):QMainWindow(parent){
      .....
      Level1AWidget *l1aw = new Level1AWidget(this);
      Level1BWidget *l1bw = new level1AWidget(this);
      //layout management l1aw and l1bw object
      ......
  }
```

Children widgets

```
 class Level1AWidget: public QWidget {
      .......
      private:
        Level1AWidget *l2aw;
        Level1BWidget *l2bw;
      .......
 }
```

l1aw object creates l2aw objects in constructor

```
  mainWidget::mainWidget(parent):QMainWindow(parent){
      .....
      Level1AWidget *l2aw = new Level1AWidget(this);
      //layout management l2aw and l2bw object
      ......
  }
```

How should i connect l2aw object to main object?

Comment: Why do you want to use signal/slot mechanism here? Your main window can call functions of its child widget objects, child widgets call functions of their children and so on. In other words you can perform direct calls through the widgets hierarchy.

Comment: Yep, but how **second level children** widget can call function of main window?

Comment: It looks like a complicated design, though. But anyways, all children can store a pointer to main window and use its API. To avoid cyclic dependencies use forward declarations (in child classes) for your main window class pointer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to use mediator pattern (get's necessary pointers from childrens). https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator